# is there a way to clear AppURL via handleOpenURL in Nativescript?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

**appURL values remain in the scope of app after it is suspended and then resumed.**

I am trying to reset the values of appURL after it has been received in App Component initialized in Nativescript Application

```
import { handleOpenURL, AppURL } from 'nativescript-urlhandler';

ngOnInit() {
handleOpenURL((appURL: AppURL) => {
console.log('Got the following appURL ', appURL);
var urlEncodedString = appURL.toString().split('out=')[1];
var json = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(urlEncodedString));
var token = json["token"].toString();
            }
}
```

or if it is possible to clear app Cache in Nativescript on app resume

Help! required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set the intent data to null once processed.

```
handleOpenURL((appURL: AppURL) => {
 ...
 ...
 // Once you process the app url, set intent data to null
 if (application.android) {
     const activity = application.android.foregroundActivity || application.android.startActivity;
     if (activity) {
         const intent = activity.getIntent();
         if (intent) {
             intent.setData(null);
         }
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: It working same as setting launchMode = "singleTask";
When i move to background (application tray/system tray) and resume application, my appurl is cleared but when i join back from the url from email or browser, the app state is persistent to the earlier state

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't define this as an entire function, rather than a function expression?

From my primitive understanding of JS, the expression is temporal/ephemeral. Trying to change an ephemeral value isn't honoring the implied expectation of that expression.

You'd be better off making a function, that when a parameter is passed, it is unique on each instance of the function object created.

```
function doThing(parameter){ do_operations_with(parameter) }
```

Each call to the function I believe will hoist the function, create the object with its own child namespace, and with each parameter passed, they will be unique to that function runtimes' namespace.

Comment: this method is an implicit call in ngOnInit()